# Can't send order parameter as variable to Binance API - Python

Tags: python, api, binance

I'm trying to send the take profit and stop loss not as a fixed price to Binance, but as a variable in order to calculate it, for instance sl = price*0.98

If I set the SL and TP with a fixed price ("price": "650" )the orders get through, but when I use the variable (see code below) I get a `[{'code': 400, 'msg': None}, {'code': 400, 'msg': None}]` response.

this is the method for the signed request( I didn't code it )

```
def send_signed_request(http_method, url_path, payload={}):
    query_string = urlencode(payload)
    # replace single quote to double quote
    query_string = query_string.replace('%27', '%22')
    if query_string:
        query_string = "{}&timestamp={}".format(query_string, get_timestamp())
    else:
        query_string = 'timestamp={}'.format(get_timestamp())

    url = BASE_URL + url_path + '?' + query_string + '&signature=' + hashing(query_string)
    print("{} {}".format(http_method, url))
    params = {'url': url, 'params': {}}
    response = dispatch_request(http_method)(**params)
    return response.json()

# get the price an calculate sl and tp

response = send_public_request('/fapi/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBUSDT')

price = float(response['weightedAvgPrice'])

TP = float("{:.2f}".format(price*1.20))
SL = float("{:.2f}".format(price*0.90))


#send sl and tp

params = {
    "batchOrders": [
        {
            "symbol":"BNBUSDT",
            "side": "SELL",
            "type": "STOP",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": SL,
            "timeInForce": "GTC",
            "stopPrice": SL-1
        },
        {
            "symbol":"BNBUSDT",
            "side": "SELL",
            "type": "LIMIT",
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": TP,
            "timeInForce": "GTC"
        },
    ]
}

response = send_signed_request('POST', '/fapi/v1/batchOrders', params)
print(response)
```

How would I need to change the code to work with the calculated SL and TP variable?

Comment: As far as I remember, prices should be a string on Binance

Comment: Plus round the resulting value to 8 decimal places. After convert to string

Comment: It should be possible because libraries like ccxt or the unofficial python-library are also injecting a variable.

Comment: I mean *python-binance* library

Comment: yes, but your vairiable is not a string it's float. Try to convert your variable to string like `str(var)`, then send it to Binance

Comment: It works! with 3 decimals btw